# How to find the parent of the BindingList?

Tags: c#, wpf

My Model is as below .

```
public class FItem
    {
        public FItem()
        {
            FSubsystems = new BindingList<FSubsystem>();            
        }

        public int RecordId { get; set; }
        public string ItemName { get; set; }


        public BindingList<FSubsystem> FSubsystems { get; set; }


    }

    public class FSubsystem
    {
        public int SubSystemID { get; set; }
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public int YearID { get; set; }
    }
```

Code :

```
FItems = new ObservableCollection<MarketRecord.FItem>();
FItems.CollectionChanged += OnUiCollectionChanged;


        private void OnUiCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
            {
                var addedItem = e.NewItems[0] as MarketRecord.FItem;
                if (addedItem != null)
                {
                    addedItem.PropertyChanged += OnColumnModified;

                    if (addedItem.RecordId == 0)
                        modifedItems.Add(addedItem);


                    addedItem.FSubsystems.ListChanged += OnColumnModified;

                }
            }
        }






private void OnColumnModified(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        if (sender.GetType().Name == "FItem")
        {
            MarketRecord.FItem modifiedItem = (sender as MarketRecord.FItem);
            if (!modifedItems.Contains(modifiedItem))
                modifedItems.Add(modifiedItem);
        }
        else
        {
            // add parent of the binding list (i.e fitem object ) add it to             modifedItems

// Find parent here 
        }

     }
```

As my code tells I need to find the parent of binding list in else clause of OnColumnModified  . How can I do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you currently structured your code this is not really possible.

You can achieve this with the help of an anonymous method:

```
addedItem.FSubsystems.ListChanged += (s, e) => OnColumnModified(addedItem, e);
```

This will register an anonymous method as the event handler for `ListChanged`. When that event is raised, it discards the `sender` argument of the event and instead passes in `addedItem`, your `FItem` instance.

You could improve the type safety of this code a bit by changing `OnColumnModified` to this:

```
private void OnColumnModified(MarketRecord.FItem modifieditem)
{
    if(!modifiedItems.Contains(modifiedItem))
        modifiedItems.Add(modifiedItem);
}
```

The event registrations would now look like this:

```
addedItem.PropertyChanged += (s, e) => OnColumnModified(addedItem);

addedItem.FSubsystems.ListChanged += (s, e) => OnColumnModified(addedItem);
```